# Displaying a ImageView in android studio just with code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview

I tried this code in the MainActivity in android studio:

```
ImageView redBlock = new ImageView(this);
redBlock.setImageResource(R.drawable.blablabla);
redBLock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
redBlock.setX(45f);
redBlock.setY(45f);
```

It doesn't appear on the screen of my phone when i run it

Comment: I know how to display the image using ImageView in XML, but i want to do it only with code!

Comment: You will have to add it to a View in your layout may be a Linear Layout which is in your Activity View. Or setContent View to that image!

Answer (score 0):

Imageview isn't included in a view group so that's why not a appear
you can refrence a ViewGroup such as LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout, or any other ViewGroup then add you image view to it e.g.

```
    LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.container);
    ImageView redBlock = new ImageView(this);
    redBlock.setImageResource(R.drawable.blablabla);
    redBLock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    redBlock.setX(45f);
    redBlock.setY(45f);
    ll.add(redBlock)
```

Comment: when you create the LL linearlayout what the "container" should be (in the "R.id.container") do i have to create something else? because my project is just the standard one android studio creates when you start a new one.

Comment: you should add this Linear layout to the xml file of this activity with id container